# How would gRPC work in the context of a chatbot?

Tags: grpc, chat, chatbot

I'm trying to build a customer chatbot for an ecommerce site for a school project. The chat should allow the user to be able to access a live customer-service agent if the customer is not satisfied with the chatbot's replies. I've been recommended to read up on GRPS by the TA, but am still a bit confused on how it would work. I'm confident that I'd need to use gRPC-Web, but I noticed that this does not support bi-directional streaming. Do you have any recommendations for what else I could do?

Comment: Stack overflow discourages questions that entertain opinion-based answers. I think your analysis has been good. Even if gRPC-Web were able to support bidi-streaming, it seems over-engineered to use gRPC in this case unless there's a need to support (existing) gRPC backends or other non-browser (chat) clients. WebSocket would be worth considering.